# List of selected faces after shortest_path_select()

Tags: python

How can i retrieve the list of selected verts/edges/faces after selecting the shortest_path_select() ?

I can see in the viewport that the correct faces are being selected, but from code i cannot see them selected, neither from the bmesh neither from the mesh itself.

[image]

As you can see in the image, after the call to bpy.ops.mesh.shortest_path_select() i see the faces selected in the viewport, but from code only the face 655 of the mesh results selected.

After calling the function i DO call bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me) but still it seems not to work as wanted.

Here a snippet of code driving this example

```
                bpy.ops.mesh.shortest_path_select()

                bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)

                self.report({"INFO"}, f"me 655: {me.polygons[655].select}")
                self.report({"INFO"}, f"me 380: {me.polygons[380].select}")
                self.report({"INFO"}, f"me 372: {me.polygons[372].select}")
                self.report({"INFO"}, f"me 947: {me.polygons[947].select}")
                self.report({"INFO"}, f"me 2200: {me.polygons[2200].select}")
                self.report({"INFO"}, f"")

                self.report({"INFO"}, f"bm 655: {bm.faces[655].select}")
                self.report({"INFO"}, f"bm 380: {bm.faces[380].select}")
                self.report({"INFO"}, f"bm 372: {bm.faces[372].select}")
                self.report({"INFO"}, f"bm 947: {bm.faces[947].select}")
                self.report({"INFO"}, f"bm 2200: {bm.faces[2200].select}")
                self.report({"INFO"}, f"")
```

I don't know how to get the list of selected faces after the shortest path calculation.
Any hep?

Answer (score 2):

**Unclear what the issue is.**

Will mention that when a mesh is put into edit mode, the edit mode mesh is a "snapshot" of the data when mode toggled.  It is not written back to the mesh datablock until mode is toggled back. (Or other methods are called to implicitly save edit mode changes)

```
>>> C.object.update_from_editmode(
update_from_editmode()
Object.update_from_editmode()
Load the objects edit-mode data into the object data
```

Hence looking at `bpy.data.meshes["Foo"]` data while "Foo" is being edited will not show updates.

Little test script.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

ob = bpy.context.edit_object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

def print_selection(element_type):
    selection = [e.index for e in getattr(bm, element_type)
                 if e.select]
    print(f"{len(selection)} {element_type} selected")
    if selection:
        print(f"    {selection}")



print("Before")
for sel in ("verts", "edges", "faces"):
    print_selection(sel)
bpy.ops.mesh.shortest_path_select()
#bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me) # Not required.
print("After")
for sel in ("verts", "edges", "faces"):
    print_selection(sel)
```

Run on default grid.

[image]

Output to console

```
Before
8 verts selected
    [11, 12, 21, 22, 77, 78, 87, 88]
8 edges selected
    [6, 29, 31, 32, 139, 155, 157, 158]
2 faces selected
    [10, 70]
After
28 verts selected
    [11, 12, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33, 42, 43, 52, 53, 54, 55, 62, 63, 64, 65, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88]
40 edges selected
    [6, 29, 31, 32, 34, 48, 50, 51, 52, 53, 69, 71, 72, 88, 90, 91, 93, 95, 107, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 130, 132, 133, 135, 137, 139, 149, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158]
13 faces selected
    [10, 19, 20, 29, 38, 47, 48, 49, 58, 67, 68, 69, 70]
```

Again with two initial verts selected

[image]

```
Before
2 verts selected
    [11, 88]
0 edges selected
0 faces selected
After
15 verts selected
    [11, 12, 13, 14, 24, 34, 44, 45, 46, 56, 66, 76, 86, 87, 88]
14 edges selected
    [6, 9, 12, 35, 54, 73, 76, 78, 96, 115, 134, 153, 156, 158]
0 faces selected
```

And again, but modifying to also show the mesh selection, deselect all verts, toggle into object mode and back to edit mode, select two verts and  run script

```
def print_selection(element_type):
    lut = {"verts" : me.vertices,
           "edges" : me.edges,
           "faces" : me.polygons,
           }
    selection = [e.index for e in getattr(bm, element_type)
                 if e.select]
    print(f"{len(selection)} {element_type} selected")
    if selection:
        print(f"    {selection}")
        
        print([lut[element_type][i].select for i in selection])
```

Result.

```
Before
2 verts selected
    [11, 88]
[False, False]
0 edges selected
0 faces selected
After
15 verts selected
    [11, 12, 13, 14, 24, 34, 44, 45, 46, 56, 66, 76, 86, 87, 88]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
14 edges selected
    [6, 9, 12, 35, 54, 73, 76, 78, 96, 115, 134, 153, 156, 158]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
0 faces selected
```

[What is the bmesh equivalent to bpy.ops.mesh.shortest_path_select()?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186067/what-is-the-bmesh-equivalent-to-bpy-ops-mesh-shortest-path-select)

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. My key problem was the way i was getting my bmesh.
I setted the active object into edit mode and then created a new bmesh from the contex.active_object In your code you get reference with bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me) which actually solves my problem entirely. Thank you!