# How to get vertex indices in order by script?

Tags: scripting

[image]
In that image, none of the vertex have the same xyz coordinate, and there is also no face.

just like the title how can I get their indices in order, with result like this

```
indices = [0, 4, 5, 2, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Related: [How can I sort vertex positions sequentially indices in a closed area?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/191649/how-can-i-sort-vertex-positions-sequentially-indices-in-a-closed-area/191689#191689) and [What is the bmesh equivalent to bpy.ops.mesh.shortest_path_select()?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186067/what-is-the-bmesh-equivalent-to-bpy-ops-mesh-shortest-path-select/186137#186137)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/191649/how-can-i-sort-vertex-positions-sequentially-indices-in-a-closed-area/191689#191689 -> you can copy paste leanders answer -> it works